# IE10 Hover + Pseudo Elements

Tags: css, hover, pseudo-element, internet-explorer-10

Example: http://codepen.io/mastastealth/pen/gFjhi

Basically, I have an element with an :after element set to opacity 0. On hover, it goes to opacity 1. Apparently it works in IE9 and everywhere else, but not IE10 (unless I click)? Ideas?

Comment: Try giving it a `z-index`: http://codepen.io/Blender3D/pen/rhsLe

Comment: Does that work for you? It remains the same as far as I can tell. Plus, a child element will always be on top of it's parent anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears there is a bug where the selector with a pseudo class followed by a pseudo element is not listened for when an event happens. If you add the listener by simply adding the selector with only the pseudo class your style will be applied on the event occurring.

http://codepen.io/justinphillips/pen/qvHyi

```
.p:hover:after {
    opacity: 0.7;
  } 

.p:hover {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently IE10 continues the horrible bug of not accepting :hover on divs. Example updated using an  element instead and it works fine.