# CSS hover only working with anchors in IE10?

Tags: css

I have tried a few really basic css hovers which work on all browsers except ie10. My question now is what is going on? It only works on anchor tags. Is there any work-around? I tried specifying a background-color but that doesnt work.

I read a lot on stackoverflow but non of it seems to be related to my problem.

```
.block-active {
    margin: 0px 0px 0.5% 0.5%;
    height: auto;
    opacity:0.7;
    width: auto;
    padding: 1.7% 1.8% 1.7% 1.8%;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
    font-size: 210%;
    position:relative;
}
.block-active:hover {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: please, coding style :/ however, msie/ff/opera/webkit, try there prefix like -ms-transition, -o-transition, -webkit-transition and -moz-transition

Comment: If memory serves me, IE10 does not accept the `:hover` pseudo selector on `div` elements. An alternate option would be to make it a separate class(ie `.active`) and then toggle the class on hover with Javascript.

Comment: I can't see you're using background-color in your anchor???

Comment: @APAD1 I tried that but how do I hover the current element using javascript? When I did a mouseover function and added an active class it affected all items

Comment: You have to assign the class to only the element you are mousing over by using the `this` selector `$('.block-active').mouseover(function() { $(this).toggleClass('active'); });`

Comment: @APAD1 dont you think it is extremely weird that this doesnt work? I mean ie10 and 11 are modern. Javascript works.

Comment: Yes, it is weird. I believe it may be a bug, at least according to [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114526/ie10-hover-pseudo-elements) I found.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found out what was wrong! The answer is so retarded that I didn't belive it would work but it did.

Simply add this at the page beginning (before `<html>` tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Yep, Internet Explorer...

Otherwise the `:hover` works only on `<a>` and `<button>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question but the code below works for me (IE10, Win7 on Virtual Machine)

Another option is to use Javascript.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.block-active {
background-color: #0f0;
margin: 0px 0px 0.5% 0.5%;
height: 50px;
opacity:0.5;
width: auto;
padding: 1.7% 1.8% 1.7% 1.8%;
transition:opacity 0.5s;
position:relative;
}
.block-active:hover {
opacity:1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block-active"></div>
</body>
</htm>
```